# 20.10 Raspberry Pi Snap GIMP install error

Tags: libreoffice, snap, raspberrypi, gimp

I have Ubuntu 20.10 on a Raspberry Pi4.

sudo apt install gimp

works just fine, it installs GIMP version 2.10.18 and all is well.

Just for the hell of it I decided to remove this .deb installation of GIMP and try a snap installation instead. Expecting to get GIMP version 2.10.22 I tried:
sudo snap install gimp

I got the error:

/////

error: cannot perform the following tasks:
Ensure prerequisites for "gimp" are available (cannot install prerequisite "kde-frameworks-5-core18": no snap revision available as specified)

/////

I am not too upset by this because the .deb install works just fine. More importantly I read posts by people having challenges with snap installed GIMP even when the install was successful.

I assume the failed install is a bug.

Does anybody know if Canonical is planning to migrate the installation of major applications like Libre Office and GIMP away from .deb to Snap ?

If this happened it would hopefully give Ubuntu LTS users a simple way to get current versions of major applications.

Comment: This PPA supports ARM, https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/gimp, if you would like to get the latest version of GIMP without using snaps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the gimp snap depends on the kde-frameworks-5-core snap

although the gimp snap is available for arm architecture (used by the raspberry pi), the kde-frameworks-5-core snap is only available for amd64 architectures

[image]

obviously, not a good situation

ideally the kde package should be made available also for arm architectures for the gimp snap to be usable on the pi

Comment: FYI - I created an issue in the gimp github issue tracker - not sure they'll be able to avoid the kde dependency and maybe kde would need to do something instead - https://github.com/snapcrafters/gimp/issues/137 - I don't think ubuntu will move gimp away from deb until this snap issue would be solved

Comment: Koen, thank you very much for raising this in the correct place

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to install GIMP 2.10.22 in ARM architecture is to use the Ubuntu Handbook [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/gimp) for GIMP. In addition to `amd64`, it supports `arm64` (Raspberry Pi 3,4) and `armhf` (Raspberry Pi 2).

Open a terminal, and enter the following commands one by one.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install gimp
```

I am assuming that OP asked the question to know how to get the latest GIMP in ARM, and mentioned snap because it is one of the possible ways to get latest software.

Comment: I'm quite happy with GIMP 2.10.18. I raised the question more through curiosity about snap and Canonical's likely progression with the migration of Ubuntu to more widespread use of snap.